# Why is PHP explode returning an array of arrays?

Tags: php, arrays, explode

I'm using PHP 5.6.31 and executing this very simple explode statement, but it's not behaving as I would expect.

```
$mystring = "48-72";
$myarray[] = explode("-",$mystring);
var_dump($myarray);
```

I would expect this to print:

```
array(1) {[0]=> string(2) "48" [1]=> string(2) "72" }
```

But instead it prints this:

```
array(1) { [0]=> array(2) { [0]=> string(2) "48" [1]=> string(2) "72" } }
```

So now I have to get my values like this:

```
$value1 = $result[0][0];
$value2 = $result[0][1];
```

Is this normal behaviour, to return an array of arrays, or is it something I'm doing?

Comment: Because you assigned to `$myarray[]`, which is like `array_push()`.

Comment: Just assign to `$myarray`.

Comment: Explode returns a single array (as documented in the manual). But you're placing that inside another array, hence what you're seeing.  `$myarray = ...` will just assign it to a regular variable.

Comment: Thank you all!  Easy fix.

Comment: Ps your php version is years out of date and out of support. Upgrade urgently to a supported version to ensure you have the latest features and security fixes.

Comment: I would love to upgrade but first I have to upgrade thousands of instances of mysql to mysqli or pdo.  I'm working on it.

Answer (score 0):

You should change your code to the following :

```
$mystring = "48-72";
$myarray = explode("-",$mystring);
var_dump($myarray);
```

Comment: ....an average answer just dumps the code. A _good_ answer explains what has changed and, more importantly, why it needed to be changed.

Comment: What @ADyson is trying to say here: you should invest a bit more effort into explaining your code. What changes you made and way. Maybe a reference to the documentation. Maybe a suggestion for refactoring the approach. Not just the code ...